# Why component composition as an alternative to Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

The old React docs [recommend](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) component composition as an alternative to Context. I don't understand this recommendation though.

From what I understand, Context is intended to be a solution for prop drilling. But with component composition, you still need to prop drill. You're just drilling a component instead of data. In the example from the docs, we're drilling `userLink` instead of `user` and `avatarSize`.

Comment: I think the documentation is clear. *However, sometimes the same data needs to be accessible by many components in the tree, and at different nesting levels. Context lets you “broadcast” such data, and changes to it, to all components below.*  So, in this case, context is more simpler than component composition.

Answer (score 0):

Component composition would probably be better presented here as an *intermediate* solution. It avoids *worsening* the prop drilling issue, when the payload becomes more complex, while keeping the explicitness of prop requirement.

I agree that the doc may emphasize too much this alternative when introducing it with:

> If you only want to avoid passing some props through many levels, component composition is often a simpler solution than context.

I would consider this doc as a warning for many inexperienced developers, who may (too) quickly jump to Context when facing the example situation:

> It’s also annoying that whenever the `Avatar` component needs more props from the top, you have to add them at all the intermediate levels too.

...so the doc shows an easy decoupling solution through component composition, which is in fact, as you point out, essentially bundling a more arbitrary payload prop.

Therefore there is still some prop drilling indeed.

But there are plenty other situations where Context is more appropriate, not just for prop drilling BTW, as also explained in the doc.